# Sharing React components between projects while keeping the source code in one of them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I am looking for a way to share React components (as well as their Flow types and their SCSS) between 2 projects while keeping the source code for the components in one of the projects. The second project would then have a read-only usage of the components from the other project.

However, because the main project is deep inside a directory in a Git repository, I can't add a NPM dependency to the second project of the first project (the `package.json` in the first project is not at the root git directory).

For now, the only option which I have found is to have a script that manually copies all the code from the directory of the first project to the other. However, I was wondering if there is a more "standard" way of doing this.

Comment: Why not extract out the React Components in a separate (private?) npm library and install it as a dependency in both the projects + support for the projects that might be using it in the future?

Comment: Or you could try using local path to the package see the official docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths

Answer (score 2):

Try using git submodule. Here's [its documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).

Let's say you have Project1 and you want to use it in Project2.
To make it simple, add `.gitmodules` file in the root directory of the Project2. Inside that file is this:

```
[submodule "src/project-1"]   //you can change the path to wherever you want to put the Project1 inside Project2
   path = src/project-1   //same as above mentioned path
   url = git@github.com/your-project-1-repo.git
   branch = master //branch of Project1 that you want to use, usually in the master
```

Then, run this commands within Project2

```
git submodule init
```

And whenever you have changes in Project1, just run

```
git submodule update --remote
```

in your Project2 to update the Project1 that you are using in Project2

Answer (score 0):

You can have it as a NPM dependency and import from it even if its in a nested [directory](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders). Actually your application can be totally oblivious as to where the package actually resides if you are using webpack (or any module bundler) using [resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/).

In conclusion : no need to have this component as the `main` of a package.json. Its presence in the `node_modules` makes it available. Your module bundler can make it easy to import through configuration. Version can be controlled using git with the NPM/yarn support of git urls for installing packages.